# restful url convention : same resource multiple level

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-webapi, restful-url

My question is about the correct way to name the route in a .net core web API of the following case:

Here is the database schema on which my question is based

[image]

1- I want the ability to GET all stores, so i have :

```
/api/store
```

2- I want the ability to GET all Professor and Student, so i have :

```
/api/student
/api/professor
```

3- the problem

I don't want to retrieve cascading data, so when I query my student or teacher resource I have:

```
Student :
{
  "IdStudent": 1,
  "FavoriteStoreId":2
}

Prof :

{
  "IdProfessor": 1,
  "FavoriteStoreId":2
}
```

So if i want "FavoriteStore" object, i need to call `api/store/2` after first call to api/student/1 and retrieve FavoriteStoreId.

but what if i want to get favoriteStore in one call ?

is it a right way to do something like :

```
api/student/1/store or api/student/1/favorite-store
```

so i have multiple URL which potentially returns a store :

```
api/student/1/store GET student favorite store
api/professor/1/store GET professor favorite store
api/store GET all store
```

but all of this, is the same resource ( same entity behind -> Store table )

so i wanted to know if this is a good way to go?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the right way is call api/store/2 after first call to api/student/1 and retrieve FavoriteStoreId.

Since if you want to get the student's FavoriteStoreId you also need firstly get the student id and then get the store id. This is two steps.

If you directly call  api/student/1/favorite-store, you also need firstly get the student and then get the store. This is also two steps.

In my opinion, there is no difference. But if you call call api/store/2 after first call to api/student/1 and retrieve FavoriteStoreId, this could be understand better than you create a new api method.